# Programatically copying data from table from offline database to online database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a local database and an online database. When i make an entry into my local database, it should also automatically make an entry in the online database. Can anybody tell me how I can do that?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Can you tell us more about what you're doing with the database? For example, do you need to read the secondary while the first is still read/write? Do you need to be able to write to the secondary as well? Are there any data transformations necessary between them?

Answer (score 2):

The key concept you need to study is called "[Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)".

Comment: i think Replication will be useful for me but i got error when i want to replicate my online database. It Says "Sql server replication Requires Actual Server Name and i am using IP". How Can i Resolve it?

Comment: That's a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8212032/1595345).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it programmatically there's the [MS Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/sync/bb821992.aspx).

Comment: Can u Give me Example for That?

Comment: Sorry no, I can't.  I was researching synchronisation technologies recently and came across this.  I thought it might be relevant to you.  I haven't implemented it, though.  Follow the links and you may find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Service Broker can provide this functionality.  It uses a store-and-forward messaging model.  Your local edition may not have this available, however.